# Cannot select parent div class

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm working on a simple jQuery element but I can't seem to select the right div.  I have 2 divs called "container_vragen" and inside the div are some hidden div's. Now I have some buttons that shows that hidden div but it shows it in both "container_vragen" divs. But I want to show it in only one of the divs.

```
$('.open_sub_ja , .open_sub_no').click(function() {
        $(this).parents().find('.submenu').fadeIn(500);
    });

    $('.akkoord').click(function() {
        $(this).parents().find('.submenu').fadeOut(500);
    });
```

I have a small jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/YGArt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your ancestor with a selector :

```
$(this).parents(".container_vragen").find('.submenu').fadeIn(500);
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/Y4AR7/).

Comment: Yup I just realized my mistake! The parents() goes back to the body div (I think) if you don't put a div in the value of the parents().

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `parents()` for `parent()` , like this:

```
$(this).parent().find('.submenu').fadeIn(500);
```

Because [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) will return all parents until document root, that is not what you want, you just want to go one parent up to then find the `.submenu` element, so to just go one parent up you use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parent()` instead of `.parents()`

Check jQuery API docs given at http://api.jquery.com/parents/